# How to export crash-free users from firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, google-bigquery, crashlytics, google-fabric

I want to persist data about crashes and metrics of crash-free users in my database for further analyze.

[image]

I have already linked the project to BigQuery, but can't find a way to calculate **crash-free users** value by data, which contained in BigQuery.

It's possible to export crash-free users metrics in some way?

Answer (score 2):

Fabric/Firebaser here -

The Firebase Crashlytics export to BigQuery doesn't include crash-free users because Google Analytics for Firebase is needed to calculate the crash-free users statistic. You can export Analytics data to BigQuery as well, however if you're using BigQuery sandbox you'll have to upgrade for that.

Once that's exported, you should be able to calculate the crash-free users value by counting distinct users with an "app_exception" event. This would look something like the following:

`1 - (distinct users with app_exception / distinct users)`